# Laravel 5 image resize

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I use Laravel 5 and have a form to upload a image. When saving the file I have in my controller methods to get the image and put it in a directory:

```
if ($request->hasFile('picture')) {
    $destinationPath = 'uploads';
    $filename = $image->getClientOriginalName();
    $extension = $image->getClientOriginalExtension(); // add
    $picture = sha1($filename . time()) . '.' . $extension; //add
    $offer->image = $picture;
    $image->move($destinationPath, $picture);
}
$offer->save();
```

Before I save the file I would like to resize the file with a max. width of 800px. Is there a image resize or compression function in Laravel available?
What would be the best idea to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can install and use package, similar to [intervention](http://image.intervention.io/).

Example from official website:

```
$img = Image::make('public/foo.jpg');
$img->resize(320, 240);
$img->insert('public/watermark.png');
$img->save('public/bar.jpg');
```

Comment: How I can get the image in my example and pass it as parameter within Image::make() ?

Comment: use path to image?

Comment: Just use path to an uploaded image as first parameter.

Answer (score 0):

```
Image::make($request->file('image'))->resize(462, 462)->save('upload_path/filename.jpg'));
```

try this code

Comment: Please give some explanation as to what is going on in the code. Code dumping is frowned upon here.

Comment: First add this package to your app. here is the package installation details.
http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/installation
then try to follow the instruction and using process from the documentaion