# OctoberCMS: Cropping the original image on upload

Tags: laravel, image-resizing, octobercms

Given the following code:

```
$car= new Car();
$car->name = Input::get('name');
$car->photo = Input::file('photo');
$car->save();
```

I need to crop the photo (with offset) before saving it. I tried using the [ImageResizer](https://github.com/toughdeveloper/oc-imageresizer-plugin) plugin but couldn't figure out how to integrate its API with the above code.

Comment: Did you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36133906/laravel-5-image-resize#36134047 ?

Comment: @Tim Yes but could not get it working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can `resize image` using that `plugin` but you even don't need it as internally it also use `OctoberCMS built-in Resize function`.

First you need to save it on disk and then resize it in-place.

> for this you can use October Cms's in-built `Resizer` https://octobercms.com/docs/api/october/rain/database/attach/resizer

**You can also crop image if you need just read** https://octobercms.com/docs/api/october/rain/database/attach/resizer#crop doc and you are good to go. **There are lot more options if you need.**

```
<?php namespace hardiksatasiya/...somethig;

use October\Rain\Database\Attach\Resizer;

// ...

$car= new Car();
$car->name = Input::get('name');
$car->photo = Input::file('photo');
$car->save();

// code to resize image
$width = 100;
$height = 100;
$options = []; // or ['mode' => 'crop']

Resizer::open($car->photo->getLocalPath()) // create from real path
          ->resize($width, $height, $options)
          ->save($car->photo->getLocalPath());
```

This code will open saved Image, Resize it and save it in same place.

If You get any problem please comment.

Comment: Hi. When I try to crop the photo `Resizer::open($car->photo)->crop(10, 10, 100, 100)->save($car->photo->getLocalPath());` I get this error: `Call to undefined method October\Rain\Database\QueryBuilder::guessExtension()`. Removing this line of code fixes the error. Did you test this code and it worked?

Comment: I didnt check it but if this also gives you error i will check and correct it after testing, for now I see In resize there is different instance of file, modified code `Resizer::open($car->photo->getLocalPath())` just check it if it works or not and let me know.

Comment: sorry for posting without testing I was in little hurry so.. but i will test it when i get free.

Comment: Thanks. I will test it and get back to you as soon as possible.

Comment: Thanks. This is saving the image twice, once the original image and then the resized one. Do you think it's possible to crop and save at once?

Comment: i will check it and let you know, it should override old one but i will check it.